# Uploading bundle to S3

Tags: amazon-s3

When I upload a Mac bundle to S3 (i.e. bundle.bundle) using the web interface it is appending the extension .zip to the file.

This is undesirable and I can see that it does not seem to add an extension to other files.

1. How do I know when S3 will append to the filename
2. Does this only happen through the web portal (i.e. through an SDK will this happen?)

Comment: Are you saying that this behaviour takes place when using the Amazon S3 management console?

Comment: Yes. Through the management console.

Answer (score 0):

Are extensions hidden on your Mac/Finder maybe? so the extension is there, but it's not displayed.

It looks like a manual procedure, why not rename the file afterwards?

Comment: No, it actually is a zip file when uploaded to AWS. In other words I need to unzip it to be able to use it like a normal bundle.